# Cannot find method createAllDayEvent(string,string,object)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I have 1 problem. I want to sync my google sheets with calendar.
I went on google instructions and made this script

```
function addEvents() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("some spreadsheet id").getSheetByName('Oswiadczenia');
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("some id");
  var currentCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("some other id");
  var events = currentCalendar.getEvents(new Date(2010, 01, 01), new Date(2030, 01, 01));
  for (var j = 0; j < events.length; j++)
  {
    events[j].deleteEvent();
  }
  var data = ss.getRange('A2:C' + lr).getValues();
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    cal.createAllDayEvent(data[i][0], data[i][1], {description: data[i][2]});
  }
}
```

But its not working. I dont know what to do.
It says:

> Cannot find method `createAllDayEvent(string,string,object)`. (line 17,
>   file "Code")

Why?
What I need to correct?

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter for [createAllDayEvent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createAllDayEvent(String,Date,Object)) should be a date, not string. You should convert data[i](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createAllDayEvent(String,Date,Object)) to Date before calling the createEvent method.